# Linux Mint: Set eth0 to static IP now linux won't boot

Tags: linux, networking, boot, linux-mint, ethernet

I set my desktop running Linux Mint 16 to a static ip. The idea being I could connect to the desktop as a server. This way I could access my bitnami lamp stack from my laptop if I wanted to program in another room.

When I did a reboot Mint will not boot. Not even into recovery. It just gets stuck on "Loading Initial Ram Disk"

I imagine it was a config problem with the Ethernet. So I disabled the ethernet in the motherboard settings and was able to boot no problem at all.

I went into /etc/network/interfaces
and into etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and reset all the settings.

But when I enable the Lan controller on the motherboard. Linux gets stuck on the boot again.

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I resolved the problem myself. If anyone needs help this is what you need to do.

in etc/NetworkManager/system-connections you will find a file called Wired Connection 1 delete this file.

Then reboot. 
In motherboard configuration re-enable the Lan adapter.
reboot again

Comment: It's been my experience that if you want to use static addresses, you need to uninstall Network Manager and edit `/etc/network/interfaces` manually.  If you want to use a wired connection, you probably want to uninstall Network Manager and edit `/etc/network/interfaces` manually. If you do this, you are much more likely to keep all your hair.